# Why is molarity independent of temperature?

Tags: concentration

I can't find a good answer as to why molarity is independent of the temperature. Why is the concentration (in mol/l) independent of the temperature?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far on the question?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [molarity](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/A/A00295.html) is **temperature-dependent**.

You might have meant [**molality**](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/M/M03970.html), because molality is **temperature-independent**.

The reason is very simple, if you see molarity definition, molarity is the amount of substance of solute per **litre** of solvent and that mean it depends on **volume**.
You know that volume depends on temperature, therefore molarity is also temperature-dependent.

Molality on the other hand is the amount of substance of the solute per mass of the solvent, both are independent of the temperature.